# ImportError: No module named integrate

Tags: python

I tried to solve a differential equation using lib `odient` in python, and this is what I wrote in `gedit` editor:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8  -*-
from __future__ import division 
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def phi(y,t):
    return 1.5*y*(1-y/6)

y0 = 1.0
t =np.linspace(0,5,201)
sol = odeint(phi,y0,t)

plt.plot(t,sol)
plt.show()
```

and everytime I try to execute it in terminal, here's what I get:
[ImportError: No module named integrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okgXe.png)

but when I try execute it using Ipython everything goes normal, here's a screenshot: [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB7fV.png)

can you please help me? thanks.

Comment: Try to post the text of the error message instead of a picture (the screen shot of the result is helpful though)

Comment: Don't call your file `scipy.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing scipy module.

Please Install it first.

```
$ sudo pip2 install scipy
```

I managed to run your program after installing additional requirement

```
$ sudo pip2 install matplotlib
$ sudo apt install python-tk
```